# Real Time Scenarios to write Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I'm very new to Spring Boot. I would like to implement a microservice by my own. Don't know how to start.
Could somebody help me by giving real scenarios to develop some code. Which application can I develop?

Comment: Typically, questions on here are very technical in nature. You're required to show what's not working in a minimal reproducible example, and then people can help.  Look up some of Josh Long's tutorials on youtube. Then do a microservice for a shoe company.

Answer (score 0):

```
        If u want to learn Springboot There is a lot of tutorials on the net just u can search u will get good resources. Once u complete SpringBoot then u can go for Microservice with SpringBoot  
        For Realsceniro u can do Starting Like Basic Like TodoMangemet Employee Mangement, 
below sample url

    https://www.springboottutorial.com/creating-microservices-with-spring-boot-part-1-getting-started
    https://www.dineshonjava.com/spring-boot-tutorial/
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you read technical books like "Cloud Native Spring in Action
WITH SPRING BOOT AND KUBERNETES" or "Microservices with Spring Boot 3 and Spring Cloud".

maybe helpful